# vim - replace all accents

Tags: vim, latex

I'm currently writing a pretty long document with latex using vim, and i need to replace all the accented characters by latex accented characters.

**Example**

```
âttaché càsè => \^attach\'e c\`as\`e
```

note that i don't want/cannot use package enabling to use accents directly in the file.

**What i did so far**

My current solution : I did several mappings to replace each accent with the correct latex formulation. I apply them on paragraphs using visual mode.

```
vnoremap   <leader>eaa  :s/é/\\'e/g
vnoremap   <leader>eag  :s/è/\\`e/g
vnoremap   <leader>eac  :s/^/\\^e/g
vnoremap   <leader>aag  :s/à/\\`a/g
vnoremap   <leader>iac  :s/î/\\^i/g
vnoremap   <leader>oac  :s/ô/\\^o/g
etc.
```

**What i'm looking for**

My solution is pretty inconvenient because if my current paragraph has different accents, i have to select it and apply my mapping several times.

Is there a way to apply these all at once ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: There used to be an utility that did that conversion back and forth, but I can't remember its name.  Perhaps you should ask on [tex.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this function in my setup for years:

```
function Entities()
  let b:winview = winsaveview()
  silent s/Á/\&Aacute;/ge
  silent s/á/\&aacute;/ge
  silent s/Â/\&Acirc;/ge
  silent s/â/\&acirc;/ge
  [... and 234 more lines like these ...]
  if(exists('b:winview'))
    call winrestview(b:winview)
  endif
endfunction
```

You could adapt it to your needs pretty easily:

```
function LatexAccents()
  let b:winview = winsaveview()
  silent s/è/\\`e/ge
  silent s/ê/\\^e/ge
  silent s/à/\\`a/ge
  silent s/î/\\^i/ge
  [... and so on ...]
  if(exists('b:winview'))
    call winrestview(b:winview)
  endif
endfunction
```

I must add that running 238 substitutions on a single line or paragraph sounds really stupid and wasteful but Vim doesn't care and the whole thing is pretty much instantaneous.

NB: the "view" part is there to keep your cursor in place.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: In TeX `î` is supposed to be written as `\^\i`, not `\^i`.  The latter has an extra dot.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, well I was going with the OP's substitutions. If he is wrong, tell him.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain those into a single command using `|` (here escaped by a `\` as it's part of the map definition, not "define the map then run this substitution"):

```
vnoremap yourMapping :s/é/\\'e/g \| '<,'>s/è/\\`e/g " … other substitutions separated by \|
```

I would also add a `<Ctrl-v><enter` at the end to avoid having to press enter to run the substitution. And a `e` flag to supress `No match` errors that would break the following commands.